# why click event is not adding qty in the cart

Tags: reactjs

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {productId: '', qty: 0, isCart: true}
  }

  addToCart = (pid) => (
    this.setState((state) => (
      {productId: pid, qty: state.qty + 1}
    ))
  );

  removeCart = () => (
    this.setState({isCart: false})
  );

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(1)}>Add to Cart</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(2)}>Add to Cart</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(3)}>Add to Cart</button>
        <Cart productId = {this.state.productId} qty={this.state.qty} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Trying React Component Lifecycle Methods when fetching data from parent to child it does not reflect anything qty still 0. 
I don't know why please guide. here is code

Thanks

```
https://codepen.io/Jack_8588/pen/GbZbZB
```

Comment: This should work as it is. I'm talking about only this piece of code. Your state logic is somehow buggy. Your `product` and `qty` is not in sync. You are changing product ids here but quantity is always incrementing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errorname already gave a good answer, but i also have to add that

3/ use props in the child component, in the Cart class, replace `this.state.qty` with`this.props.qty`

Here is the changes I did to your Codepen:

```js
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Product extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {productId: '', qty: 0, isCart: true}
    this.addToCart = this.addToCart.bind(this)
    this.removeCart = this.removeCart.bind(this)
  }

  addToCart(pid)  {
    this.setState({productId: pid, qty: this.state.qty + 1
      });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  removeCart() {
    this.setState({isCart: false});
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(1)}>Add to Cart</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(2)}>Add to Cart</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(3)}>Add to Cart</button>
        { this.state.isCart && <Cart productId = {this.state.productId} qty={this.state.qty} />}
        { ! this.state.isCart && <h3>Cart has been removed</h3>}
        <button onClick={this.removeCart}>Remove Cart</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {qty: this.props.qty}
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if(props.qty !== state.qty) {
      return {qty: props.qty}
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Invoked immediately after component render');
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(this.props.qty !== nextProps.qty) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.props.productId !== prevProps.productId){
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('component is unmounted and destroyed');
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Cart Items ({this.props.qty})</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Product />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I was wrong, see @Brumor's answer below

Comment: I don't get the point here. Even with an arrow function, OP's code should work. No need to use a regular function or use `bind` here. Am I missing something?